# how does ifstream readsome exactly work

Tags: c++, thrift, ifstream

What I want to do is, send a file 8kB at a time. (Without filling RAM with full file)

This is my Code:

```
while ( file.good()){
    file.readsome(sinLine,8000);
    client.saveFile(_return, std::string(sinLine), file_name);
}
```

file is a `std::ifstream` for a text file.
client is a `thriftClient`, (I don't know how relevant that is, to the problem)
`sinLine` is a `char * [8000]`

The problem is that the recieved file is 242.2kB and the sent file is 142.6kB.

In the debugger I noticed that it went through the loop more than 18 times (142 / 8 = 17.25), but it doesn't go on forever(I don't know exactly how many times, but it's probably 242 /8 times).

I also noticed that every third loop (3, 6, 9...) the value of `sinLine` wasn't showing in my IDE (QtCreator).

So my questions are, how does `readsome()` work? and am I using it right? or should I be using a different function? or is maybe the conversion from char * to `std::string` not correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `readsome()` is fairly useless and probably doesn't do what you are hoping for. It determines the number of guaranteed to be available characters by calling `in.rdbuf()->in_avail()` which itself calls the `virtual` function `showmanyc()`. The default implementation of this function is to return the number of characters known to be the in the buffer (i.e. `egptr() - gptr()` on the `std::streambuf`). The function then carries on to simple `read()` that many characters using `in.rdbuf()->sgetn(buffer, n))`.

Note that you can use `in.gcount()` to determine how may characters were actually read but the last unformatted input function. That's giving you a better count of characters read than determining the number of characters up to the next null character. Especially as the unformatted input functions make no attempt to null terminate the read data.

Also, your check is for `file.good()` isn't great: assuming you go unlucky and the last successful read ends exactly at the last element, the last input will be processed twice. I would strongly recommend using a loop more like this:

```
for (char buffer[8196]; file.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)); ) {
    client.saveFile(_return, std::string(buffer, buffer + file.gcount()), file_name);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I tried your solution, and it worked much better! Unfortunatly the file is still not the same size :/ instead of 142kB it is 160kB now. Could you have any idea why that is?

Comment: @Anthony: what are differences? Did you open the original file in binary mode? If the original file is using text mode and the destination doesn't a rewrite of the end of line sequences that may account for some differences. It may be reasonable to verify separately that reading the file works OK by writing it to a temporary file.

Comment: I noticed what the problem was, it was a stupid mistake, I was adding a   "\n"   on the write side lol removed it and now it works just like I want it to! thank you very much, I accepted your answer!